# How do I send different puppet class based upon node name?

Tags: puppet

I hope this question isn't too basic, but it seems like there is no definitive answer on the internet.

I am trying to send a specific module to a node based upon the fully qualified domain name.

I don't want to copy and paste the default, but would be happy if there were a way to use puppet to do a case or if statement based upon the node.

For example: if the node name is foo, include module bar, but continue to parse the default classes without a break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node 'foo' inherits default { 
    include bar
}
```

Comment: The following link seems to contradict this: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_node_definitions.html#inheritance

Comment: It is A solution. It is not recommended, but alternatives are not easy to explain in here either, e.g., you have to use ENC or Hiera with Parametrized classes etc...

Answer (score 0):

A good way to use a specific module for a node based on the `FQDN` is following the `Assigning a Class to a Node With Hiera` example in the [Puppetlabs documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/complete_example.html).